# How can seprate string in three parts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I want to Substring the string which is delimited

```
ABC/123/DEF
```

I want in

```
ABC in 1st column
123 in 2nd Column 
DEF in 3rd Column
```

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: Do you want to `update` or `select` existing table data, or `insert` new data?

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and specify the expected result. What do you want if the string only has 1 `/`, or 3, or 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database in sql server you can try this:

```
declare @t table (name varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('ABC/123/DEF')

select PARSENAME(replace(name,'/','.'),3),PARSENAME(replace(name,'/','.'),2) , PARSENAME(replace(name,'/','.'),1) from @t
```